# Repetition alarm in Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I need to schedule a certain repetition alarm, that can happen any day of the week, several days. It can be on Monday, or every weekday, or only the weekend days- and of course this needs to be stored in the DB.

My question is, how could I store this in the DB? I thought of using an int array of seven positions, and depending on whether which position is a true (or 1) I'll assume there's an alarm that way.

Any other ideas? Suggestions please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: the AlarmManager has the self repeting call, so it can be set there only, m sorry but why we need a db store here, if neccesary it can be stored to SharedPreferences only.

Comment: @twntee we need a DB, because if we're going to store an alarm for Sunday, and today is Monday, the user might want to switch off the phone; and if this happens, the alarm is lost unless it's stored in the DB

Comment: yes offcourse, i understand, but then we can store it in preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store a single `byte` to represent your week and pull values out of it using a bitwise `&` operation. Bit 1 could represent Monday, Bit 2 Tuesday, etc. You can use this to represent all combinations of days, e.g:

```
01100000 - Saturday/Sunday (Weekend)
01110001 - Friday/Saturday/Sunday/Monday (Long weekend)
```

When reading the value you would use something like:

```
byte val = 0x71; //01110001
boolean mondayActive = (val & 0x1) == 1;
boolean fridayActive = (val >> 4& 0x1) == 1;
```

**EDIT comment**
This assumes that you are already familiar with the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and were looking for a  mechanism to track your alarms as you cannot use a single alarm to schedule events in the manner the OP described. If you need to mimic cron in a single task, possibly take a look at something like the [BuzzBox](http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/scheduler) SDK.

**EDIT write sample**

```
public static final int MONDAY  = 0x01;   //00000001
public static final int TUESDAY = 0x02;   //00000010
public static final int WEDNESDAY = 0x04; //00000100
public static final int THURSDAY = 0x08;  //00001000
public static final int FRIDAY = 0x10;    //00010000
public static final int SATURDAY = 0x20;  //00100000
public static final int SUNDAY = 0x40;    //01000000

//example values to write
int weekend = SATURDAY | SUNDAY; //01100000
int longWeekend = FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY | MONDAY; //01110001

//and as per flightplanner's comment, to read
boolean mondayActive = (weekend & MONDAY) == MONDAY;    //false
mondayActive = (longWeekend & MONDAY) == MONDAY;        //true
```

Comment: +1 I'd also use basically use this method, although I think the code's easier to read if you declare some constants for each day of the week, so for example `public static final int MONDAY = 0x01;` `public static final int TUESDAY = 0x02;` and then do the test as `boolean mondayActive = val & MONDAY == MONDAY`. This is also slightly more efficient as it saves the bit shift.

Comment: Totally agree, both about using constants and losing the bit shifts. The example code was to make it clear what was going on as some developers are less familiar with bitwise operators.

Comment: Great answer, as well as the BuzzBox SDK. I guess with the byte representation, this could easily be stored in the DB and just grabbed and processed in order to know when the alarm should be created! Thanks!

Comment: how could I then easily edit the already created repetition alarms, using this? For example let's say the user wants to have Monday, so I store 1000000 but then, the user wants only weekend, so I should switch it for 0000011?

Comment: Firstly it's up to you how you represent the data, but remember there are 7 days and 8 bits. Building the value to store would use the bitwise or operator. See the comment from @flightplanner, I'll add small sample.

Comment: @JohnMark13 and how would I modify then the values?

Answer (score 0):

**AlarmManager** provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running. Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.

Here you have a tutorial: [Tutorial on Android AlarmManager](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/)

Answer (score 0):

follow up on Diego answer You typically use the `AlarmManager` for this. 
Create an intent that will wake up the below `AlarmReceiver.class` that is a `BroadcastReceiver`.
AlarmManager is firing of this `intent` at your `dateForAlarm`. The `dateForAlarm` can be a `String` in the DB like "2009-04-14 15:16:45"

When device is restarted you need to recreate all alarms and use another or same `BroadcastReceiver` to get all dateForAlarm from DB and create the alarms.

put this in your manifest to capture a restart signal to your `BroadcastReceiver`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Code:

```
Calendar dateForAlarm = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" // example date.."2009-04-14 15:16:45"
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(WAKE_UP_AND_ALARM_NOW, "value you want to send to MyBroadcastReceiver like "god morning"");
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Get the AlarmManager service 
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateForAlarm, sender);
```

Comment: thanks, I was just asking for the best way to store the data in the DB so it can easily be retrieved when BOOT_COMPLETED and recreated the alarm. I already have the BroadcastReceiver :)

Comment: This way it's also easily readable in the DB. It's easily searchable in the DB and it's respectfully easy to work with for fellow developer. Accept my answer if it's working ok.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @JohnMark13's answer and @noloman's question "how would I modify then the values? ", I would like to add this.

To modify values, you can use bitwise operatoes. I will explain different cases:

**To enable a day:**
Suppose you want to add monday to an alarm. Take a number 0x00000001 and OR it with your current value (i.e. a|b). The value returned will have the Monday enabled. Similar masks can be made for rest of days depending on their bit location. For weekends, use 0x01100000.

**To disable a day:**
Suppose you want to remove monday from an alarm. Take a number 0x01111110 and AND it with your current value (i.e. a&b). The value returned will have the Monday disabled. Similar masks can be made for rest of days depending on their bit location. For weekends, use 0x00011111.

**To switch previous value of a day:**
The mask for Monday is 0x00000001. If you XOR the value with this mask (a^b), it will reverse the bit of monday from the value, hence add/remove it depending on previous value. For weekends, the mask will be 0x01100000.

Hope that helps.